# CodeIgniter MVC - Is it a good practice to have Models serve views?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I'm developing a news website using CodeIgniter 3. Almost every page contains a **Notice Board** content of which is same on all pages. I have created a view for this section named 'noticeboard.php'. And different pages are controlled by different Controllers. i.e. Home, Post, Gallery, Poll, etc. The problem using controller here is I need to perform two operations on every controller to generate the noticeboard HTML.

Controller looks like:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class SomeController extends CI_Controller {        

    /* .. */

    public function index() {
        /* .. */
        $noticeboard['notice'] = $this->noticeboard_model->getNotice(); // Gets Notice's HTML
        $data['noticeboard'] = $this->load->view( 'sidebar/noticeboard', $noticeboard, TRUE );
        /* .. */
        /* $data is served to main page template */
    }

    /* .. */

}
```

And `views/sidebar/noticeboard.php` looks like:

```
<div class="noticeboard">
    <h3>Notice</h3>
    <?php echo $notice; ?>
</div>
```

I could solve this code redundancy by simply having a `getNoticeboardHTML()` on **Noticeboard** model and having the model fetch the view and return HTML. But is it a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better you create a custom library and put `getNoticeboardHTML()` in that class. After that call this wherever you need. Do not dirty your model with HTML.

[Create Custom Library](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically speaking, **No**. You are not supposed to do this. Its a violation of MVC. You could use a library class to avoid the code duplication.